# How to serialize a dictionary to an array of json objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a dictionary as shown below:

```
var tableData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
tableData["name"] = "Sam";
tableData["city"] = "Wellington";
tableData["country"] = "New Zealand";
```

How can I convert the above dictionary to a serialized json data as below:

```
[
   {  "key": "name", "val": "Sam" },
   {  "key": "city", "val": "Wellington" },
   {  "key": "country", "val": "New Zealand" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the [`JsonSerializer#Serialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-7.0) method and the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-select-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1)))) method for the provided `Dictionary` that projects each element of a sequence into a new form like below:

```
var tableData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
tableData["name"] = "Sam";
tableData["city"] = "Wellington";
tableData["country"] = "New Zealand";
        
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(tableData.Select(elem => new { key = elem.Key, val = elem.Value }));
//ok, it prints [{"key":"name","val":"Sam"},{"key":"city","val":"Wellington"},{"key":"country","val":"New Zealand"}]
Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
```